# string doesn't appear in JFrame

Tags: java, string, swing, jframe, draw

I've been trying to draw a string in a JFrame, but for some reason it wont show , here is the code with the drawings command:

```
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 500);
g.drawImage(backToMain,0,0,this);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawString("name", 300, 0);
```

but for some reason the screen I get is white with the Image in the left corner but missing the String.
I thought I might have a problem with the `paint()` command but I have tried several other things but it seams that the string just refuses to appear.

Comment: Your code scares me, but, try adding a positive position to the `y` position...something like `g.getFontMetrics().getAscent()` should just about do the trick.  Then take a look at [Working with Text APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html)

Comment: thanks dude, i guess that was it , i just started progreaming so.. lol

Comment: Good luck then, don't forget to have fun ;)

Comment: Also, don't draw directly on the JFrame. Draw in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of a JPanel that is displayed in the JFrame

Comment: ya i'm drawing in the paintComponent(Graphics g), thanks :)